# Inconsistent theme Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Shell 3.10.4

Tags: gnome, themes

I use the Libra theme and i have put the theme under usr/share/themes.
I want the theme to look like my terminal.

[image]

Comment: The picture doesn't exist.....Could you please re-upload?

Comment: @joejoe31 i refresht the link should work now, sorry.

Comment: I still don't exactly understand what you are asking...

Comment: the terminal minimize, maximize and close icons are different from the file browser. under gnome tweak tool you can select the window theme and the gtk theme and i have both set to the same theme but they look different.